# Excel VBA Pasting a Range into New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble with this one.  I am trying to paste a range, that varies based on a selection from a userform, to a new workbook.  The pasting is not working.  I've gotten feedback that I need to eliminate the use of activesheet, and name the specific targeted workbook.  I don't know how to name it if it is a new workbook.  I also don't know how to save it to the users desktop.

Anyways.  The code fails here (1st line):

```
Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Activate
Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Unprotect
Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Range("BA6::BT200").Copy
```

Below is the full code, with so you can see the action I am trying to take - passing the worksheet name variable from the userform cboExportInvoiceWeek.  Ideally, the user clicks a button and a new csv file is created.  The only variable I have is the worksheet (one for each week of year).  The cell values are static.

Again, **my issue is the actual pasting into the new workbook.**

```
Private Sub cmbInvoicesExport_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CurrentFileName As String
CurrentFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print "Active File: " + CurrentFileName

Dim wsexport As String
wsexport = cboExportInvoiceWeek.Value    

Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Activate
Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Unprotect
Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Range("BA6::BT200").Copy

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks(CurrentFileName).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: put Option Explicit at the top of your code and also, are you receiving any error messages? And your DIsplayAlerts code, as is, isn't doing anything.

Comment: Subscript out of range.

Comment: I tabbed out a line in between the display alerts to close the activeworkbook.  I've since taken it all out.

Comment: what is the value of wsexport when it fails?

Comment: Maybe try to activate the workbook first then in a separate line the sheet within that workbook

Comment: What is cboExportInvoiceWeek? A range? Write debug.print Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").name before the line that throws the error. If the new debug.print line throws an error, you know that that particular workbook is not open and you must provide full path to workbook to open it and access its worksheets. Then write debug.print wsexport or debug.print Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).name. If this new debug.print line throws an error, then you know the sheet does not exist or not under the name you are expecting.

Comment: Start by adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module (as per the first suggestion) and then **declare all your variables and objects!**  It's got to be a problem with either `wsexport` or `cboExportInvoiceWeek` and since neither of them are [visibly] declared, it could even be **both**.

Answer (score 0):

Generally: I would check err.number after each suspicious step. 
In details:

1. VBA drops subscript error when either the file is not open or the referred worksheet does not exist. So I would split Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Worksheets(wsexport).Activate to

   Workbooks("Restaurant Manager -Master.xlsx").Activate

   Worksheets(wsexport).Activate
2. For SaveAs I would put the desired filename to a variable and see how it looks. You might have to specify a path either. And you can see err.description too.
3. You can find the path to desktop in a few ways, e.g. so:

   sPath=environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\"

See more on this here: [enter link description here](http://codevba.com/office/environ.htm#.WkdTft_iYdU)